# Criteria Query in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, criteria

```sql
SELECT reportcategory.categoryName, 
       reportcategory.categoryId 
FROM   reportcategory AS reportcategory 
WHERE  reportcategory.categoryId = 1
```

I want to write above query using Criteria. `ReportCategory` is my pojo class and table with the same name in the database.

Please help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Hibernate, here is an example:

```
List cats = sess.createCriteria(Cat.class)
.add( Restrictions.like("name", "Fritz%") )
.add( Restrictions.between("weight", minWeight, maxWeight) )
.list();
```

More details at following [Criteria Queries](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/querycriteria.html)

Equivalent query for your case would be:

```
List result = sess.createCriteria(Reportcategory.class)
.add( Restrictions.eq("categoryId", new Integer(1)) )
.list();
```

Cheers !!

Comment: my question is how to create alias of pojo class using criteria and could fetch the result using alias

Comment: Not sure if I followed but I have written a query for what you mentioned in your question.